# Simple bash script (input letter output number)

Tags: bash, scripting

Hi I'm looking to write a simple script which takes an input letter and outputs it's numerical equivalent :-

I was thinking of listing all letters as variables, then have bash read the input as a variable but from here I'm pretty stuck, any help would be awesome!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter letter"
read "LET"
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5
f=6
g=7
h=8
i=9
j=10
k=11
l=12
m=13
n=14
o=15
p=16
q=17
r=18
s=19
t=20
u=21
v=22
w=23
x=24
y=25
z=26

LET=${a..z}
if
  $LET  = [ ${a..z} ];
  then
  echo $NUM
sleep 5
echo "success!"
sleep 1
exit
else
  echo "FAIL :("
exit
fi
```

Comment: Could you post the code you have?

Comment: can you tell with some example output with the example input?

Comment: Updated sorry guys :)

Comment: You never set NUM to anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo "Input letter"
read letter
result=$(($(printf "%d\n" \'$letter) - 65))
echo $result
```

0

ASCII equivalent of 'A' is 65 so all you've got to do to is to take away 65 (or 64, if you want to start with 1, not 0) from the letter you want to check. For lowercase the offset will be 97.

Comment: Hi thanks so much could you explain in more detail whats happening?

Comment: Look here: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif . ASCII table is a set of signs (letters etc.) with their number equivalents (every sign in computer is represented as a number). %d defines the way of printing the letter- %d means decimal so it will be displayed as a number. Then, you have to subtract 65 because you want to have 'A' not equal to 65 (again look at the ASCII table), but 0, 'B' not equal to 66, but 1, 'C' not equal to 67, but 2 etc.

Comment: Also, `info printf` reads: * If the leading character of a numeric argument is \`"' or \`'' then
     its value is the numeric value of the immediately following
     character.  Any remaining characters are silently ignored if the
     \`POSIXLY_CORRECT' environment variable is set; otherwise, a
     warning is printed.  For example, \`printf "%d" "\'a"' outputs \`97'
     on hosts that use the ASCII character set, since \`a' has the
     numeric value 97 in ASCII. *

Answer (score 2):

A funny one, abusing Bash's radix system:

```
read -n1 -p "Type a letter: " letter
if [[ $letter = [[:alpha:]] && $letter = [[:ascii:]] ]]; then
    printf "\nCode: %d\n" "$((36#$letter-9))"
else
    printf "\nSorry, you didn't enter a valid letter\n"
fi
```

The interesting part is the `$((36#$letter-9))`. The `36#` part tells Bash to understand the following string as a number in radix 36 which consists of a string containing the digits and letters (case not important, so it'll work with uppercase letters too), with `36#a=10`, `36#b=11`, …, `36#z=35`. So the conversion is just a matter of subtracting 9.

The `read -n1` only reads one character from standard input. The `[[ $letter = [[:alpha:]] && $letter = [[:ascii:]] ]]` checks that `letter` is really an ascii letter. Without the `[[:ascii:]]` test, we would validate characters like `é` (depending on locale) and this would mess up with the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

use these two functions to get chr and ord  :

```
chr() {
   [ "$1" -lt 256 ] || return 1
   printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$1")"
}

ord() {
  LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$1"
}


echo $(chr 97)
```

a

Answer (score 0):

USing od and tr

```
 echo "type letter: "
 read LET
 echo "$LET" | tr -d "\n" | od -An -t uC
```

OR using -n

```
echo -n "$LET" | od -An -t uC
```

If you want it to start at a=1

```
echo $(( $(echo -n "$LET" | od -An -t uC) - 96 ))
```

#### Explanation

Pipes into the tr to remove the newline.
Use od to change to unsigned decimal.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Maybeeee, i forgot to change it to the real one, i have edited it now :)

Answer (score 0):

late to the party: use an associative array:

```
# require bash version 4
declare -A letters
for letter in {a..z}; do
    letters[$letter]=$((++i))
done
read -p "enter a single lower case letter: " letter
echo "the value of $letter is ${letters[$letter]:-N/A}"
```